# How to stop turtle when in position -200, 0

Tags: position, turtle-graphics

How to stop turtle at -200,0
When i set it to = -200, 0 it says invalid syntax

```
t.speed(20)
t.goto(-200, 0)
t.color('red')
t.fillcolor('yellow')
t.begin_fill()
t.width(3)
while True: 
    t.fd(400)
    t.lt(170)
    if abs(t.pos()) < -201:
        t.end_fill()
        break
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I basically want the the turtle to stop at -200, 0 coordinates

Comment: When i set it to = -200, 0 it says invalid syntax

Comment: What does "set it to = -200, 0" mean? Could you share that exact line of code? Your existing code is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test has some problems:

```
if abs(t.pos()) < -201:
```

The `abs()` of any number can't be less than a negative number.  Also, `pos()` doesn't return a number, it returns a `tuple`.  I'm guessing what you really want is:

```
if t.distance((-200, 0)) < 1:  # turtle positions are float, not exact
```

Complete solution:

```
import turtle

turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.setx(-200)
turtle.width(3)
turtle.color('red', 'yellow')

turtle.begin_fill()

while True:
    turtle.forward(400)
    turtle.left(170)

    if turtle.distance((-200, 0)) < 1:
        break

turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Note that fill pattern is system dependent in this case due to lines crossing.

Comment: Also if i want it at the Y Axis is it t.height?